# Photoshop Texture Overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, texture

im just wondering how you would go about making this texture overlay in photoshop. im familiar with masks and blending modes but i just cant get it looking right. 
any help would be great. 
cheers
[image]

Comment: I see at least 6 various "texture overlays" Any clue as to what, specifically, you are referring to?

Comment: yep. im referring to the grungy texture that sits over the blue, black and grey background. its best seen in the lower left of the image

Comment: What are you struggling with though? Identifying what that texture IS or you think you know what it is and are struggling with HOW to apply it? Would really help to see your attempt so we can better say what you might be missing.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this grunge wall affect, but the easiest way to achieve this would be to create the colour layers first or backgrounds (ie: in your example, the blue brush stroke, the black brush and the gray image).

Then what I would do is create a layer on top of those and use a grunge brush over them in a black shade. You may want to lower the opacity afterwards so it doesn't overpower the BG

There are so many grunge brushes out there, deviat art is a great place to find them. Something like this: http://www.deviantart.com/browse/all/?section=&global=1&q=grunge+wall+brush

Then I would sugest playing around with blend layers like levels and curves to get the darkened areas to appear better.

With these kind of things to get the best results, you should do as many individual layers as you can, and overlay them so they blend in, that's basically what this person has done and then you can get some really nice work.

Comment: +1 Good explanation. This is how I would have done it, except for the grunge brush. I would've gotten a concrete texture or similar, desaturated it, adjusted brightness and contrast/levels and set the layer blend mode to multiply or screen depending on the image.